# calculating time complexity of complex functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am learning how to find the time complexity of an algorithm. I am unable to find out the time complexity (in terms of big O) of the following function:

```
6n^3/(logn +1)
```

Is there any easy way to calculate it?

Comment: You need the concrete algorithms with the _implementation_ of your  value type for _n_ to calculate the complexity of your code.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just trying to give an asymptotic description of the function in question? In that case `O(n^3/log n)`. If not and the question was meant as asked, then as @clemens says, you need to have an actual algorithm to analyze.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, but a [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)